Configure Apache Hop to receive json from web
I have a web app where I need to send some json data to an on prem server running hop.
I'm struggling with the correct pipeline configuration.
I tried using a REST client transform, but it seems like it's not consuming the json. Moreover I might be misunderstanding the transform and this transform is for using apache hop for sending requests to external applications.
What would be the correct transform for receiving data on apache hop?

I decided to pull the data instead of sending it.
